# Populating textbox from combobox selection

Tags: c#

I am writing a program with two tabs.  On the first tab the user enters information about a Customer's account.  On the second tab there is a combobox which holds the account's name and when selected the same information entered on the first tab being stored should populate the textboxes with the same information on the second tab.  I have done this before and i am using the same structure but it is not working.  I also am drawing this information from an associated class but everything looks right.  Can someone tell me what is wrong.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ArrayList account;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        account = new ArrayList();
    }

    //here we set up our add customer button from the first tab
    //when the information is filled in and the button is clicked
    //the name on the account will be put in the combobox on the second tab
    private void btnAddCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            CustomerAccount aCustomerAccount = new CustomerAccount(txtAccountNumber.Text, txtCustomerName.Text,
            txtCustomerAddress.Text, txtPhoneNumber.Text);
            account.Add(aCustomerAccount);

            cboClients.Items.Add(aCustomerAccount.GetCustomerName());
            ClearText();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Make sure every text box is filled in!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
    }


    private void ClearText()
    {
        txtAccountNumber.Clear();
        txtCustomerName.Clear();
        txtCustomerAddress.Clear();
        txtPhoneNumber.Clear();
    }
```

this is where i'm running into trouble. It says that there is no definition for "accountNumber" or any of the others

```
    private void cboClients_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtAccountNumberTab2.Text = account[cboClients.SelectedIndex].accountNumber
        txtCustomerNameTab2.Text = account[cboClients.SelectedIndex].customerName;
        txtCustomerAddressTab2.Text=account[cboClients.SelectedIndex].customerAddress;
        txtCustomerPhoneNumberTab2.Text=account[cboClients.SelectedIndex].customerPhoneNo;
    }
```

Comment: `account` refers to an `arraylist`. Looks like you're missing a cast. Or even better, change your `arraylist` to a `List<CustomerAccount>`.

Comment: If you're not constrained by your version of .Net, have a look at replacing ArrayList with a more modern generic collection. Here's a good read http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_Generics_Recipes%E2%80%94Replacing_the_ArrayList_with_Its_Generic_Counterpart

Answer (score 2):

ArrayList holds objects, You will need to cast it to CustomerAccount

```
private void cboClients_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CustomerAccount custAccount = account[cboClients.SelectedIndex] as CustomerAccount;
     if(custAccount != null)
     {
        txtAccountNumberTab2.Text = custAccount.accountNumber
        txtCustomerNameTab2.Text = custAccount.customerName;
        txtCustomerAddressTab2.Text=custAccount.customerAddress;
        txtCustomerPhoneNumberTab2.Text=custAccount.customerPhoneNo;
    }
}
```